# Correct Syntax to pass database sequence next val parameter in ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory

Tags: spring-integration

As an example, I have a database sequence created in Oracle Db:

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE temp_seq
  START WITH     1000
  INCREMENT BY   1;
```

I want to use the result of this sequence as a SQL parameter in my insert query, the SQL is along the lines of:

```
  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES (:sequenceNumber)
```

column SEQUENCE_NUMBER is NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)

And setting the parameter goes a little something like this:

```
  public ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory sourceFactory() {

    final ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory sourceFactory = new ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory();
    sourceFactory.setParameterExpressions(parameterExpressions);
    sourceFactory.setSqlParameterTypes(parameterTypes);
    

     final Map<String, String> parameterExpressions = new HashMap<>();
     parameterExpressions.put("sequenceNumber", "T(temp_seq.NEXTVAL)");


     final Map<String, Integer> parameterTypes = new HashMap<>();
     parameterTypes.put("sequenceNumber", Types.VARCHAR);

     
     return sourceFactory;
     
    
     }
```

If I do a select SELECT MYTABLE.SEQUENCE_NUMBER;

I get : SEQUENCE_NUMBER='java.lang.Object@753f4d41'

I want that it should insert 1001, 1002, 1003...on consecutive inserts.

Comment: Why not simply put that allin a query, instead of 2 queryes? Something like `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES (temp_seq.nextval)`.

Comment: Yes that was the first solution that came into my mind, but i have to add something to sequence before inserting it.

The value that needs to be added comes in payload so in my java file i would do:
temp_seq.nextval.concat('somevalue')

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a suitable answer in java, so i did the old way, putting value directly in sql:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES (:temp_seq.nextval||''||:userId))
```

Thanks M.Dienum !!

Though i still would like to do this from my java code.

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` can accept a SpEL expression any complexity and even can call some bean method via `@` operator. So, if you are able to call you sequence and concatenate it with some Java code, just place it inside a bean method and call that from an expression. You also can pass a parameter to that method from the request message context. for example:

```
 parameterExpressions.put("sequenceNumber", "@sequenceBean.nextValue(payload)");
```

However you need to keep in mind that this is going to be as two SQL calls: one for sequence from that method and another your main `INSERT INTO`.

There is another solution like put everything into a stored procedure. See docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures.

But probably the way you have it with that `:temp_seq.nextval||''||:userId` is much better and no need to worry about Java any more.

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan